# Finding when multiple objects meet each other when they start from different points and same direction on a circular track

Tags: circles, kinematics

This is my first ever time asking a question here, so bare with me if something's not right.

So, I don't understand this whole problem, and if anyone is willing to explain it, i'd be really thankful

So there is a circular track of $6 \text{km}$. There are $3$ objects moving with $40 \ km/h, 55 km/h $, and $\frac{100}{3} \ km/h$ respectively. The track is divided by points $A,B,C$. $AB=3km \ , BC=1km ,\ AC=2km$. All objects move counter clockwise. the $1^{\text{st}}$ object starts from the point $A$, the $2^{\text{nd}}$ from point B and the $3^{\text{rd}}$ from point C.

And I need to find time) of their first meeting point (no matter where on the track but they all have to meet). The time is in hours, and is a natural integer.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: By 'don't understand' do you mean you don't understand the question or do you mean that you're not able to solve it?

Comment: @SujalMotagi im not able to solve it. unfortunately.

Comment: The 3 objects are moving at different speeds on the same track so they are bound to meet at some point of time. The question asks when that happens.

Comment: @SujalMotagi exactly. i understand that but i can't solve the question. i wanted somebody to solve it for me with explanation

Comment: A point moving counter clockwise on a circle has the form $(rcos(wt+p), rsin(wt+p)$ where r is the radius, $v=rw$ is the velocity and p is the starting angle in radians, measured from the positive x axis. Actually, the answer hint given is a better way to go.

Comment: Would you be able to solve a simpler question, for example with two objects starting at the same point on the track? And what about two objects starting at different points? If you can do the latter for objects A&B and also for A&C, then you can solve the question for three objects too.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That's a good tip. Thank you.